# Search for Arabic text ignoring diacritics or accents in SQL server

Tags: arabic, diacritics

i have characters which are considered the same in Arabic (like Alef 'ا' and Alef with Hamza 'أ'), but these are two different characters in SQL database systems. When i try to make a search function in my website, for example, i want to ignore the differences between these characters. The use of case-insensitive collation like utf8_unicode_ci won’t solve the problem. The 'ا' and 'أ' aren’t considered equal in the character mapping

Is there any solution in SQLServer ?

Regards & Thx in advance

Comment: Looks like this is answered here [dba.stackexchange.com: Treating certain Arabic characters as identical](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14153/treating-certain-arabic-characters-as-identical), if not some dbms allow you to add custom collations.